# Custom SimpleSyncProvider creating zero byte files

Tags: c#, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework, memorystream

I have a *FileSyncProvider* and I've written a custom implementation of the *FullEnumerationSimpleSyncProvider*. When files are synced from the *FullEnumerationSimpleSyncProvider* to the *FileSyncProvider* they are created correctly, but are zero bytes.

When synchronising in the other direction (FileSyncProvider as source) everything works as expected.

This is my *IFileDataRetriever* implementation. I've put breakpoints on the *FileStream* property setter and getter and the *Size* property of the *Stream* is always correct, never zero. The actual *Stream* itself is a *MemoryStream*, could that be causing any problems?

```
public class FileDataRetriever : IFileDataRetriever
{

    private System.IO.Stream fileStream;

    public string AbsoluteSourceFilePath
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("AbsoluteSourceFilePath is not supported for this implementation of IFileDataRetriever");
        }
    }

    public FileData FileData { get; set; }

    public System.IO.Stream FileStream
    {
        get
        {
            return this.fileStream;
        }
        set
        {
            this.fileStream = value;
        }
    }

    public string RelativeDirectoryPath { get; set; }
}
```

**Update:**

If, as an experiment, I modify the code as below, a 5 byte file is created:

```
    public System.IO.Stream FileStream
    {
        get
        {
            return new MemoryStream(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
        }
        set
        {
            this.fileStream = value;
        }
    }
```

So this tells me that it should work fine with a MemoryStream. If I put a breakpoint on the getter, it always looks valid whenever it's called - it has the correct size etc, not 0 as the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it! All I needed to do was reset the Position of the Stream to 0. It was at the end of the stream, hence writing 0 bytes.